# Equation tag not showing

Tags: equations, labels

Sorry, real noob here... I just need to typeset the following equation.
I found a way to split the too long equation into two lines, but now it does not typeset/give equation tag: why?

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    W [ & \text{inverse distance attraction} \\
    & \mid \text {elliptic orbits and the "second law"}] \approx 1 \label{a3}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

[image: Equation without tag]

I am using TeXShop on Mac Os X.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please not that in 99% of all latex questions, the editor is irrelevant

Answer (score 6):

The `equation*` environment is untagged. Drop the asterisk and use `equation` instead.

Comment: Yes, thanks thats it!!!

Answer (score 5):

I guess that you only need to remove the asterisk in the begin and end equation:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    W [ & \text{inverse distance attraction} \\
    & \mid \text {elliptic orbits and the ``second law''}] \approx 1 \label{a3}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Also, don't use the character `"`, called dumb double-quote marks, for typestting; use ``` `` ``` to open the quote and `''` to close.

Comment: Yes, thanks thats it!!!

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of adding a sentence to your answer, to point out that one shouldn't use "dumb" (1"`) quotation marks in a LaTeX document. Feel free to revert.